# Bottom div sliding when clicked top div

Tags: jquery, css

I'm developing a project using css and jquery and I have some problem which I couldn't solved.

[image]

Demo: http://anitur.streamprovider.net/test/liste.html
When clicked second div, why third div is sliding ? how to solved this problem ?

You can see my codes which is the on the top (Demo link)

Comment: For me too! Works as expected!

Comment: @Goldenowner yes exactly problem is big white space..I don't want to this.

Comment: It is default behavior. It will move because all div are inside same div and relative to other.

Comment: @sn0w click second div and see big white space bottom first div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your webpage has structuring issues, see when you are toggling the second div the height of second div increases by around 80px and as this whole div structure is inline aligned the third div goes down, as it should be.

what you need to do if you want to get rid of this is you need to slice your page vertically rather than horizontally,

[image: this is how your DOM structure should be]
[image: currently it is like this]

Comment: when I set height for my all div then overlapping ? (sorry my english)

Comment: okay, there is an instant solution, set the height of div container to >380px, if you do not want to go and restructure your whole html


    .otel-cift-listeleme {
        height: 400px;

    }

Comment: but then without clicking big white space seeing ? I mean when I clicked second div why third div sliding ? why third ? bottom of second div is empty ? if I have four div and if I clicked second div and then fourth div sliding it wasn't be a problem.. (my english is not enought to explain my problem .. sorry @Siddharth )

Comment: look the problem is your markup, 'DIV' is block element, it starts rendering where the last element finished, in this case last element for third div is second div, man you need to understand the inline/default behavior. it is default setting.

Comment: [read this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) this will help you out i think

Comment: I read it but I do not understandy I'm new to in English and not enough. I have to fixed or I can't sleep all night and thanks for everything.

Comment: listen i understand, apply this rule 

**.otel-cift-listeleme {
    height: 380px;
}**

Comment: I know and I did it bu my toggle div is staying under another div and content of toggle can be  changeable.

Comment: i know man, that is why i asked you to change the markup of page, read my answer carefully, you need to cut the page vertically.